# sub query result not successful

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, subquery

I have a problem in sub query in sqlite query result. When executing the below query successfully returns the result in Sqlite database but when running the program it does not returns any value. What I’m doing wrong in the below program. Please advice.

Query:

```
select * from (SELECT count(*), col2,col9,col4 FROM tbl_data_1  WHERE col4=6  AND col3 BETWEEN '2012-11-21' AND '2013-04-19' GROUP BY col2,col9,col4) as inr_qry where col2= '20016' and col9='3'
```

Program in java:

```
Vector<Vector> dataList = new Vector();
for (int i =0; i < listRows.size(); i++){
    Vector cols = new Vector();             
    cols.add(listRows.get(i));
    for (int j = 1; j < listColumns.size(); j++){
        // below query will be dynamic
        String inner_query = "select * from (SELECT count(*), col2,col9,col4 FROM tbl_data_1  WHERE col4=6  AND col3 BETWEEN '2012-11-21'               AND '2013-04-19' GROUP BY col2,col9,col4) as inr_qry where col2= '20016' and col9='3'";

        PreparedStatement data_st = database.getConnection().prepareStatement(inner_query);
        ResultSet data_rs = data_st.executeQuery();
        while (data_rs.next())  { // result not successful, result set not having records
            SLogger.printD("data_rs.getString(1): " +data_rs.getString(1));
            cols.add(data_rs.getString(1));
        }
    }
    dataList.add(cols);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need `PreparedStatement`. Instead use this:

```
Statement stmt = database.getConnection().createStatement();
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds weird but  as a int is expected, can you try to use

```
getInt(1)
```

instead of

```
getString(1)
```